# Magento reindex via script does nothing

Tags: php, magento, reindex

I've create a controller and write an action to create a category, assign product to it and re-index data. Reindex code:

```
$processes = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();
$processes->walk('setMode', array(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME));
$processes->walk('save');
$processes->walk('reindexAll');
$processes->walk('reindexEverything');
echo "Reindex Data ok <br>";
```

Then I run it, it created some lock file in var/locks. In Admin/Catalog/Manage Category, I can see that my category have products on it, but when I go to this category on front-end, It say

```
There are no products matching the selection.
```

I have to run re-index script manually via command-line

```
php indexer.php --reindex category_catalog_product
```

Then I can see list of product in front-end.
My question is, why re-index via PHP script does nothing? How can I re-index via "code-way"?
I'm currently using Windows 8.1 Pro, XAMPP 1.8.2

Comment: Please check this link http://www.kennydeckers.com/magento-programatically-reindexing-indexes/

Comment: I had tried all solution, and re-index only make change on front-end when I run it via command-line